# Moment - Angular generate array of time minus 15min

Tags: angular, momentjs, angular-moment

I have weather satellite image start date `2019_10_08_08_00.jpg`  .

l am try to generating the following array time slots with a minus of 15 min between each one. for looping images , like the following :

```
[
"2019_10_08_08_00",
"2019_10_08_07_45",
"2019_10_08_07_30",
"2019_10_08_07_15",
"2019_10_08_07_00",
]
```

Code :

```
let startTime = moment('YYYY_M_DD_HH_MM');
let endTime = moment('YYYY_M_DD_HH_MM');

if( endTime.isBefore(startTime) ){
  endTime.add(1, 'day');
}

let timeStops = [];

while(startTime <= endTime){
  timeStops.push(moment(startTime).format('YYYY_M_DD_HH_MM'));
  startTime.subtract(15, 'minutes');
}

console.log(timeStops);
```

The Problem is l get empty array in console log .

Error code :

```
moment.js:293 Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.
Arguments: 
[0] _isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _useUTC: false, _l: undefined, _i: YYYY_M_DD_HH_MM, _f: undefined, _strict: undefined, _locale: [object Object]
Error
```

Comment: You have to properly initialize both `startTime` and `endTime`, `moment('YYYY_M_DD_HH_MM')` produces an Invalid date.

Comment: @VincenzoC l cant initialize because i will get old date images !

Comment: `moment('2019_10_08_08_00', 'YYYY_MM_DD_HH_mm')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong `format` string. 
'MM' is used for month, 'mm' for minutes.

Also here is a working example

> Edit: Limit loop to 10

```js
    const now = getRoundDate();

    const timeStops = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      now.subtract(15, 'minutes');
      timeStops.push(now.format('YYYY_M_DD_HH_mm'));
    }

    console.log(timeStops);


    getRoundDate(): moment.Moment {
        const minutes = +moment().format('m');

        if (minutes >= 0 && minutes <= 8) return date.minutes(0);
        else if (minutes >= 9 && minutes <= 18) return date.minutes(15);
        else if (minutes >= 19 && minutes <= 38) return date.minutes(30);
        else if (minutes >= 39 && minutes <= 48) return date.minutes(45);
        else if (minutes >= 49) return date.minutes(0).add(1, 'hours')
    }
```

Comment: Thank you . Can i make limit loop ?

Comment: Yes of course. The current condition is 24h. That means timeStops will contain all timestamps from now + 24h, but you can change the condition as you Like it.

Comment: i did , but doesn't change. can you please edit ? i mean showing only loop limit to 10 items . but i should not mention date , event the time Continue  updating

Comment: Hi , i have question . can i round a time to the nearest 15 min ? because the output is  `[
  "2019_10_9_00_00",
  "2019_10_9_00_14",
  "2019_10_9_00_21",
  "2019_10_9_00_18",
]` ?

Comment: Not rly round but here is a small work around, _see edit_